# How to bring ActiveWorkbook to the front of the window using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I find that `Workbook.Activate` doesn't always bring that workbook to the front of the window. I wonder what is the right way to set a workbook as the top of the window so when the macro is finished this is the workbook you are looking at.

Should I use any `Windows()` based code or is this related to `.setfocus`? I am just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Just call:

```
Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Many people will read this question with a fundamental misunderstanding:

[`ActiveWorkbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeworkbook) **IS** the workbook, that is in front of all other open Excel Workbooks, unless it is currently minimized. Therefore, all you need to do to guarantee it is visible on top is to un-minimize it if it is currently minimized:

```vb
With ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)
    If .WindowState = xlMinimized Then .WindowState = xlNormal
End With                              'Alternatively: xlMaximized
```

### However! :

`ActiveWorkbook` is often erroneously used to refer to the workbook containing the running code. **This is wrong**!

The workbook containing the running code is actually referred to as [**`ThisWorkbook`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) in code!

To bring `ThisWorkbook` in front of all other open Excel Workbooks, you can therefore use

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Windows(1)
    .Activate
    If .WindowState = xlMinimized Then .WindowState = xlNormal
End With                              'Alternatively: xlMaximized
```

*Note that this **can not** bring Excel in front windows from other Apps like browsers or the file explorer!*

### Bringing the Application in Front of other, external Apps

To achieve that, you can use the [`AppActivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement) statement. This is also the answer to OP's question in the literal sense <sup>(*probably a misunderstanding!*)</sup>, it will bring the `ActiveWorkbook` in front of all other open windows and apps:

```vb
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

To do what most people probably want, bring `ThisWorkbook` in front of all other open Workbooks and guarantee that Excel is in fron of all other open Apps, we can combine the statements mentioned above:

```vb
Sub BringThisWorkbookToFront()
    With ThisWorkbook.Windows(1)
        .Activate
        If .WindowState = xlMinimized Then .WindowState = xlNormal
    End With                              'Alternatively: xlMaximized
    AppActivate Application.Caption
End Sub
```

This should solve this problem in all cases. What is mentioned below is an alternative method that only works on Windows.

---

> Alternatively, you could use the Windows API (not recommended, just for reference):
>
> ```vb
> #If VBA7 Then
>     Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
>     Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
> #Else
>     Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
>     Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
> #End If
>
> Sub SetWorkbookToForeground(Optional ByVal wb As Workbook = Nothing)
>     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
>     SetForegroundWindow FindWindow("XLMAIN", wb.Windows(1).Caption & " - Excel")
> End Sub
> ```
>
> You can use this `Sub` like this:
>
> ```vb
> SetWorkbookToForeground ActiveWorkbook
> ```
>
> or just use the API functions directly like this:
>
> ```vb
> SetForegroundWindow FindWindow("XLMAIN", > ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption & " - Excel")
> ```
>
> **Words of warning again:** Referring to `ActiveWorkbook` is almost never needed, what you most likely mean and want is `ThisWorkbook`. If you want to bring the workbook containing the running code in front of other open windows like browsers or the file explorer, replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` in the above examples!

If you have the VBA IDE open while a macro is running, it will be set as foreground window after the macro finishes and I'm not aware of a way to change that.

Answer (score 1):

`Workbook` on its own may not be qualifying enough, depending what you actually see on your screen at runtime. If the VBA runs within the same workbook, try

`ThisWorkbook.Activate`.

If your code is in workbook WB2 but processing another workbook WB1, you may want to call your VBA with that workbook as parameter and make it active at the end of your code.

So the example VBA code is in WB2 ...

```
Sub CallStuff()
    Debug.Print "Hey, I am " & ThisWorkbook.Name
    Debug.Print "starting to work on " & Application.Workbooks("Book1").Name

    DoStuff Application.Workbooks("Book1")

End Sub

Sub DoStuff(WB As Workbook)

    WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1] = "Co-cooo!"
    'do other stuff on WB
    WB.Activate
End Sub
```

situation before start of VBA ... WB2 active and executing code
[image: step 1]

after 2 lines of code WB2 still active, preparing subroutine with parameter
[image: step 2]

processed WB1, but WB2 still active
[image: step 3]

now making WB1 active
[image: step 4]

Comment: My situation is my code in one workbook called workbook1 tries to open another workbook, say, workbook2, but after this it's still workbook1 on the top.

Comment: answered by part 2 of my initial response ... updated with complete example

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and this method worked me perfectly:

```
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkBook.FullName)
```

Since this is the current workbook you are using, it won't open an another workbook but it will activate your window even if you have other apps on top.

Comment: This is remarkably simple. I've tested and works consistently.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a trick to force the workbook display on front  :

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WB2_TO_BRING_TO_FRONT.SaveAs "Error!" 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: After .activate

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Your suggestion just saved the Workbook under the name "Error!". Trying to save it with an actual illegal name like "/" did bring the Window to the front but also resulted in an error message popup. Adding `On Error Resume Next` to that code stopped the window from being brought to the front again.